# Animation of list items/redrawing Qt QListView

Tags: c++, qt

**What I'd like to achieve**:

A visual indication to draw attention to newly added items in a QListView. I had in mind having the background color 'throb' once (fading from a color to the background).

**The setup**

I have a model/view using QListView displaying QStandardItems. Qt version 4.7

**What I've tried:**

I've created a new class derived from QStyledItemDelegate. I have my own paint method to render the item. That part works. I created a QTimeLine object and set it up to create events to redraw the items.

I can't figure out how to trigger redraws of the QListView item.

In the item delegate constructor:

```
   timeLine = new QTimeLine( 3000, this );
   timeLine->setFrameRange( 100, 0 );
   connect( timeLine, SIGNAL( frameChanged( int ) ), this, SLOT( update() ) );
   timeLine->start();
```

I tried connecting to the sizehintChanged event but this does not work

```
void myDelegate::update()
{
   const QModelIndex index;
   emit QStyledItemDelegate::sizeHintChanged( index );
}
```

Any suggestions? Can this be done with style sheets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard practice to include animations into code is to use state machines.
Animations in Qt cannot be achieved using QtStylesheets. Either use QML or use QStyledItemDelegate and a state machine.

```
 /*CustomItemDelegate*/

    int state;
    enum states{
        animating,
        normal
     }

    void setstate(int state){
        this->state = state;
        /*Start animation depending on state ,by starting a QTimer and calling 
        repaint when the timer expires,also change animation variables like opacity ,         
        angle etc etc*/

    }

     void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
            const QModelIndex &index) const{

          switch(state){
               case animating:
                     break;
               case normal;
                     break;
          }
      }
    ....

 /*CustomListView*/

    slots:
       void dataChanged ( const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight ){
              ( (CustomItemDelegate)itemDelegate(topleft) )->setState(animating);
       } 
    ....


 /*Mainwindow*/
      connect(model,SIGNAL(datachanged(QModelIndex,QModelindex)),view,SLOTS(QModelindex,QModelindex));
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijith, I'll try the state machine method.

Comment: The item delegate doesn't have a repaint method. Do you have to call repaint on the view? If so, is the view the parent of the delegates?

Comment: I'm calling repaint() repeatedly on the QListView that manages the list of items. It does not update the screen. If I click on the list item with the mouse while it's animating then I get a single visual update.

Comment: Ahh, apparently it doesnt. You can add a `repaintRequest()` signal in the itemdelegate and connect it to the repaint() slot in QListview. This will inturn call repaint on the list's delegate.